# Access ExampleGroup scope outside "it" block

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm trying to DRY my spec using RSpec's Macros, and I encountered a problem.

```
describe "..." do
  let!(:blog) { create(:blog) }

  post "/blogs/#{blog.id}/posts" do
    # some macros
  end
end
```

I want to get access to `blog` variable but I don't want to do it inside `it { ... }` block so would be able to use my macros regardless of the resource (e.g. I want to apply it to `blogs`, `posts`, `comments`, etc).

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to get access to blog variable but I don't want to do it inside it { ... } block

Try not to think of `let` as normally-scoped variable definition. `let` is [a complex helper method for caching the result of a code block across multiple calls within the same example group](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-6/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let). Anything you `let` will *only* exist within example groups, meaning you can't access a `let`ted "variable" outside `it` blocks.

```
require 'spec'

describe "foo" do 
  let(:bar) { 1 }

  bar
end
# => undefined local variable or method `bar'
```

That said, if you just want to reuse the result of `create(:blog)` across multiple examples, you can do:

```
describe "foo" do
  let(:blog) { create(:blog) }

  it "does something in one context" do  
    post "/blogs/#{blog.id}/posts"

    # specification
  end

  it "does something else in another context" do  
    post "/blogs/#{blog.id}/comments"

    # specification
  end
end
```